# retrieving value of specified checkbox jquery

Tags: jquery

I am rendering a list of checkboxes with values and want to retrieve  these values as I am checking the correlating checkboxes.

```
{{each Items}}
       <tr>

           <td><input type='checkbox' name='chkRelatedTopics' value='${subject}'/></td>
           <td><label id='labRelatedTopicDisplay'>${subject}</label>
       <tr>

{{/each}}
```

as I am doing it at the moment I am getting the first value of the first checkbox rendered every time.

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name=chkRelatedTopics]", function () {

   var nameAdminUser = $("input[name=chkRelatedTopics]").val();
   alert(nameAdminUser);
});
```

How can I get the value of the subsequent checkbox I am checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get the value of the clicked checkbox for that you can use `$(this).val()`/`this.value` inside the click handler as `this` points to the clicked dom element

if you use `$("input[name=chkRelatedTopics]").val()` it will return the value of the first element matching the said selector causing it to return the same value regardless of which checkbox was selected

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name=chkRelatedTopics]", function () {
    var nameAdminUser = $(this).val();
    alert(nameAdminUser);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

change this

```
 $("input[name=chkRelatedTopics]").val();
```

to

```
 $(this).val();
```